# Is my solution for this multiple choice question correct?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f:[0,1] \mapsto R$ be a continuous function such that $f(1/2)=-1/2$ and

$|f(x)-f(y)-(x-y)|\leq (sin|x-y|^2) \forall x,y \in [0,1]$

Then $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ is ......

My attempt:

$|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-1|\leq \frac{sin(x-y)^2}{|x-y|}$

Taking limits on both the sides,

$\lim_{x \to y} |\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-1| $ $\leq  lim_{x \to y} \frac{(x-y)sin(x-y)^2}{(x-y)^2}$=$0$

$\implies$

$\lim_{x \to y} |\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-1| =0$

This implies
$\lim_{x \to y}(\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}-1)=0$

This implies $f'(x)=1$

This implies $f(x)=x+c$

From here we can calculate the value of asked integral. Is this approach correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should divide both sides by $|x-y|$ in the first step. Also $f'(x)=1$ and not $-1$. Rest everything is fine. I think.

Comment: That's  what I did.

Comment: You got $f(x)=x+c$ and you have $f(\frac{1}{2})=-\frac{1}{2} \implies c=-1\implies f(x)=x-1$.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Aditya. I know that. I just want to know if I've approached it correctly or not. Are there any inaccuracies?

Comment: Oops, sorry didn't see that. Yes, I think your reasoning is correct. You might want to add the tag: "Proof verification" or "solution verification".

Comment: Okk. Thanks for answering!!